# How to set up dynamic conditional formatting of cells in Dash - datatable

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Sup! I’m new to dash. Faced with a problem:
I have a datatable with values which i am updating by inputs through callbacks. They are working like

```
data = pd.read_excel('Sample.xlsx')

app_layout=html.Div([
    html.Div([dcc.Input(id='salary_budget_2020', type='number')]),
    html.Div([html.Div(dash_table.DataTable(
                                        id='dinamic_table',
                                        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in datafortable.columns],
                                        data=datafortable.to_dict("rows")))])
])


@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output("dinamic_table", "data"),
              [dash.dependencies.Input("salary_budget_2020", 'value')])


def update_table(salary_budget_2020):
    datafortable = data.copy()
    datafortable.at[8, '2020'] = datafortable.at[8, '2020'] - int(salary_budget2020 or 0)

    return datafortable.to_dict('rows')
```

What i want to do is to set up cell conditional formatting based on the result of a comparison between original and updated value. I found ‘filter_query’ in docs but it’s not working with my updated-value variable.

What i need is to be able to compare original value in
datafortable.at[8, ‘2020’] and datafortable.at[8, ‘2020’] - int(salary_budget2020 or 0)
to be able to change background color if datafortable.at[8, ‘2020’] < datafortable.at[8, ‘2020’] - int(salary_budget2020 or 0) and etc. Something like:

```
{'if': {'column_id': '2020',"row_index": 8,
'filter_query': 'datafortable.at[8, '2020']  < datafortable.at[8, '2020'] - int(salary_budget2020 or 0)},'backgroundColor': '#3D9970','color': 'white'}
```

Is there any way to code it?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your filter isn't dynamic. `datafortable.at[8, '2020']` isn't being interpreted in your filter query. The condition will always be `False`, so your styles will never be applied.

A simple dynamic filter could look something like this:

```
from dash import Dash
import pandas as pd
import dash_table

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3]})

x = df.at[1, "A"]

app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict("records"),
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    style_data_conditional=[
        {
            "if": {"filter_query": f"{{{column}}} = {x}"},
            "backgroundColor": "#3D9970",
            "color": "white",
        }
        for column in df.columns
    ],
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

`f"{{{column}}}` equals `{A}` in the example above.

`f"{x}` equals `2` in the example above.

So the conditional formatting logic reads: For each column if there is a cell where the cell value equals `x` apply the formatting.

---

In your callback you're only updating the data. Even if the filter stays the same, if the data changes the formatting could change. If the filter itself also needs to change based on the input you could add an output in the callback to `style_data_conditional` of `dynamic_table`. Then you could apply the idea above to make the filter dynamic.

If you only want the formatting active on a certain row you could add

```
'row_index': 1
```

inside the `"if"` dictionary.